# How to change the xml name dynamically after every automation script run

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, xml-validation, uiveri5

I am running few automation scripts in protractor and I am having one scenario where the application need unique xml file name every time to upload, so through automation how can i achieve this where i have to upload the same file multiple times by changing its file name outside as well as inside the file. It allows only xml files.

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this through nodeJS's `fs` module and appending a unique timestamp based on the current time. I haven't tested this but this may work

```
const fs = require('fs');
const newName = `file_${Date.now()}.xml`
fs.renameSync('file.xml', newName);
//Then upload your file however you need to
```

This will create a copy of `filename.xml` in the specified location and rename it `filename_1570786998048.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i will try this approach.